# how to connect to external_ip in python socket programming

Tags: python, sockets

client.py

```
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

port = 443
socket_address = (<external_ip/global ip address>,port)
print("Socket Created")

# connect to server
client_socket.connect(socket_address)
print("Socket Connected")
```

server.py

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name  = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
print('HOST IP:',host_ip)
port = 443
socket_address = (host_ip,port)

# Socket Bind
server_socket.bind(socket_address)

# Socket Listen
server_socket.listen(5)
print("LISTENING AT:",socket_address)
server_socket.bind(socket_address

while True:
    client_socket,addr = server_socket.accept()
    print('GOT CONNECTION FROM:',addr)
    if client_socket:
        vid = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
        
        while(vid.isOpened()):
            img,frame = vid.read()
            frame = imutils.resize(frame,width=320)
            a = pickle.dumps(frame)
            message = struct.pack("Q",len(a))+a
            client_socket.sendall(message)
            
            cv2.imshow('TRANSMITTING VIDEO',frame)
            if cv2.waitKey(1) == '13':
                client_socket.close()
```

I am trying to connect to an external IP over a different network but the program takes to long to connect or it refuses to connect. how do I fix this...any suggestions please!

Comment: The problem is likely not the code but the missing connectivity, i.e. firewalls blocking connections etc. If it works within the local net then the problem is not the code itself and it cannot be fixed inside the code

Comment: Is the host ip printed correct ?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich that's why I tried with different ports. do you know any way I can work this?! I am working on creating a streaming app

Comment: Again, make sure that there is connectivity in the first place - which is completely outside of your code.

Comment: Try passing an empty string as `host_ip` to `socket.bind`. This will ensure it is listening to all network interfaces. Are client and server running in the same LAN? Can you ping the server from the client?

Comment: @treuss I was trying to run same system which means server and client are on the same, rather than passing local ip I passed system's global ip which should work in my opinion. will try your solution.

Comment: @Abhinandan If the "global ip" is an external IP, then the client won't be able to connect to the server unless the network is configured to route incoming connections on that external ip to your server's LAN ip.